# Fetching values from two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I have 2 models: `Device` and `Property`. `Device` contain the following fields: `id,name` and `Property` contains: files `id,device_id,speed,time`. `device_id` is the foreign key of table `id` in model `Device`. So my models device.rb and property.rb is look as follows:

device.rb

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :properties
end
```

property.rb

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :device_id, :speed, :time
  belongs_to :device
end
```

I have to populate device details in a drop down list. It's working properly.
I also have to fetch the values from property database while selecting name from drop down.

Controller code to fetch the value by passing the device id as follows:

```
def show
  @properties = Property.find(params[:device][:id])
end
```

Test values in properties table as follows:

```
id  device_id time          speed   
1   1         13:23:00      13  
2   2         23:20:00      63.8    
3   1         10:35:        100.56
```

Device model:

```
id  name    
1   2345    
2   2345
```

While selecting device model id 1 I have to fetch the details of:

```
id  device_id     time         speed    
1   1             13:23:00         13   
3   1             10:35:00         100.56
```

In view show.html.erb as follows:

```
<% if (@properties.blank?) %>
  <p><strong>Search results not found.</strong></p>
<% else %>
  <p><strong>Available employe Details are listed below <strong></p>
  <ul>
  <% @properties.each do |c| %> 
    <li>
      <b><%=@properties.id%> <%=@properties.speed%> <%=@properties.time%></b>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

while running this am getting this error

```
undefined method `each' for #<Property:0x3ee3ff8>
10: <% else %>
11: <p><strong>Available employe Details are listed below <strong></p>
12: <ul>
13: <% @properties.each do |c| %> 
14: <li>
15: <b><%=@properties.id%> <%=@properties.speed%> <%=@properties.time%></b>
16: </li>
```

But while wring show.html.erb as in the following way only one of the data is getting

```
id  device_id     time         speed    
1   1             13:23:00         13   



<% if (@properties.blank?) %>
  <p><strong>Search results not found.</strong></p>
<% else %>
  <p><strong>Available employe Details are listed below <strong></p>
  <ul><li>
  <b><%=@properties.id%> <%=@properties.speed%> <%=@properties.time%></b>
  </li></ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: For one thing `Property.find` will return only one object. It won't be a collection, so you cannot call `each` on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@properties = Property.find(params[:device][:id])
```

will only return one Property and not an array

You need to so something like

```
@properties = Property.where(:device_id => params[:device][:id])
```

in order to get an array that you can then iterate through with each

Comment: Or: `@properties = Device.find(params[:device][:id]).properties`

Comment: @Mischa true, though this would create more database calls and unnecessarily retrieve the Device info.